# How in react app in URL always open append with "/"

Tags: reactjs, url

In react app suppose there is one route `www.xyz.com/order` when I open in browser there are two urls such as one in `/order` and another one is `/order/`

So I want to be always `/order/` even I enter `/order` only

How can I achieve this in react js app

Answer (score 0):

Add .htaccess file inside your app root(build folder).

```
RewriteEngine on
#Add Trailing slash for end of the URL
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.) 
RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: @Dharman I have to create new file as a `.htaccess` and put above code into this??

Comment: Yes, you have to put inside your build folder where your production app run.

Comment: @Dharman hey its not working Is there any other option?

Comment: @SHRADDHAPATIL I didn't write this answer. Please do not ping me.